# Data passing between Controller and DAO within PHP MVC project

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm working on a PHP MVC project, and the type of data interaction with the database is enough to facilitate the inclusion of a data access layer.  The view will use Ajax to pass JSON objects to the controller for processing.

For the controller actions that require executing DAO functions, which is best:

- Package incoming JSON into model objects and pass to DAO function
- Pass incoming JSON data directly to DAO

Right now, I'm using option 1, since the views are being developed in parallel to the controller/DAO layers and packing the data within objects is easier for writing tests.  When it comes to production, however, I am unsure if this is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using model objects to transfer data to DAO. The reasons I see are:

1. Better maintainability
2. Re-use models elsewhere and in many situations
3. Have Model specific methods in the model class and Data specific ones in the Data Access layer.
4. Sending back the model objects in JSON to the View all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I think the option number 1 is the best one. Expecially if you are going to validate data server-side. You can have a controller action which validate and incapsulate data into models that will be used by DAO functions. This solution, also, will make your DAO method more re-usable in other parts of the application (example: every DAO-method will manipulate data models... like a standard behaviour)